# Character to Bit Representation

Tags: c, character-encoding, bit

Which character has a bit representation of all zeroes?

For context, I'm wondering how to get a bit array of all zeroes and new to c/c++

```
unsigned char** result = (unsigned char**) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)
                                                * rows);
for (int i = 0 ; i < rows ; i++) {
     result[i] = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * cols);
     memset(result[i], 0, sizeof(unsigned char) * cols);
   }
```

When I then try to print the bit representation (using c & 128, c & 64, i still get bits that are set)

For example: (for rows =3 and cols = 2)

```
00100000 00110111
00000000 00000000
00000000 00000000
```

Comment: It looks ok, but could you show the full source including the part that prints out the result and sets the values of rows and cols?

Comment: This code is not correct; the first line needs allocating `rows` times the size of a `char *`.

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(unsigned char*) * rows)`, `calloc(CHAR_BIT * cols + 1, sizeof(unsigned char))`, `memset(result[i], '0', CHAR_BIT * cols)`

Comment: @Jongware Thanks! I'd completely missed the missing pointer.... solved the problem if you want to answer the question.. :)

Comment: Nah, go ahead and pick one of the others. (Although both repeat your own [casting of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first line, your malloc is allocating the wrong size. You are allocating for an unsigned char, when you should be allocating enough for a pointer to one, as below.

```
unsigned char** result = (unsigned char**) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char *) * rows);
```

This means the most significant bytes of your earlier pointers allocated within your loop are being clobbered by the succeeding malloc result. So when you look at `result[i]`, you're not actually looking at the right place in memory any more.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you misuse type

```
unsigned char**
```

And you treat it like if it was an array, but it is just a pointer to pointer to unsigned char.
Try replacing

```
unsigned char** result = (unsigned char**) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * rows);
```

with

```
unsigned char* result[] = new (unsigned char*)[rows];
```

then you can operate on variable result as on an array.

And replace

```
result[i] = (unsigned char *) malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * cols);
```

with

```
result[i] = new unsigned char[cols];
```

When freeing memory you also need to call

```
delete[] result[i];
```

and

```
delete[] result;
```

instead of

```
free()
```